# git-svn Can't locate SVN/Core.pm after fresh installation of macOS Catalina 10.15.4

Tags: macos, perl, git-svn

Recently I reinstalled `macOS Catalina 10.15.4`. After I installed `Command_Line_Tools_11.4.1`, it told me svn is no longer working with Xcode. Then I installed both git and svn by brew, hopefully git-svn would work. Unfortunately got this error message:

> Can't locate SVN/Core.pm in @INC (you may need to install the SVN::Core module) (@INC contains: /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.26.2/share/perl5 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Library/Perl/5.18 /Network/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Network/Library/Perl/5.18 /Library/Perl/Updates/5.18.4 /System/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/5.18 /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18 .) at /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.26.2/share/perl5/Git/SVN/Utils.pm line 6.

Both git & svn are the latest version.

Please help me out.

Comment: Try to [install](https://bioinformaticsonline.com/blog/view/29479/how-to-install-perl-modules-on-mac-os-x-in-easy-steps) the module `SVN::Core`.

Comment: Running into this same problem on Big Sur 11.4 - on M1 mac.  Have installed git/svn/perl through brew.  Tried installing SVN::Core through cpan but it fails due to being unable to find APR and APRUTIL

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Finally I figure it out!!!

Open the `git-svn` file (perl script, in my case file location is `/usr/local/opt/git/libexec/git-core/git-svn`), change the first line `#!/usr/bin/perl` to `#!/usr/local/bin/perl`

And it works!

I guess system perl doesn't include perl SVN/Core, but brew perl has it (dependency of brew svn).

Comment: I don't really like this solution, but it works and that's more than I can say for every other solution I've found.

Comment: Life safer! Reminds me of years ago when I last had to use subversion (and thus resorted to git-svn) and had that same (?!) perl error due to missing module or  some bug in git-svn script. Thanks. (Afternote: still needed the `cpan Term::ReadKey` command noted below by @Torello.)

Comment: [Updating the `PERL5LIB` env var](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68487977/450127) worked for me. Seems better to try that before modifying `git-svn`

Answer (score 9):

**Solution for MacOS Big Sur 11.5**

After struggling with this error for hours:

```
Can't locate SVN/Core.pm in @INC (you may need to install the SVN::Core module)
```

I've finally found a solution that actually works.

If you run:

```
brew reinstall subversion
```

It will print a message like this:

```
The perl bindings are located in various subdirectories of:
  /usr/local/opt/subversion/lib/perl5
```

Then you just need to run this command before using `git svn` to load the SVN module from the correct path:

```
export PERL5LIB=/usr/local/opt/subversion/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.30.2/darwin-thread-multi-2level
```

Comment: This worked for me as well.  Note that my version number in the site_perl directory happened to be 5.18.4 and so I adjusted the library location accordingly.

Answer (score 6):

Solution for those, who, like me - want to use Sourcetree client on macOS Catalina with git-svn:

First step:

```
brew install git
brew install perl
brew install subversion

edit
/usr/local/Cellar/git/git_version/libexec/git-core/git-svn
replace
#!/usr/bin/perl
with
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
```

Second step, install missed perl modules:

```
cpan SVN::Core
cpan Term::ReadKey
```

Third step, configure SourceTree:

In Sourcetree->Preferences - set option "use system git", from:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/git/git_version/git
```

Answer (score 3):

While not a permanent fix, a workaround is to set `${GITPERLLIB}`:

```sh
$ export GITPERLLIB=/usr/local/Cellar/git/2.31.1/share/perl5:/usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.28.2/darwin-thread-multi-2level
$ git svn clone svn+ssh://...
```

worked for me without editing any scripts installed by brew.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you've installed Perl, Subversion and dependencies via Homebrew:

```
brew install perl subversion apr apr-util
```

Install required Perl modules into `~/perl5`:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/apr/bin:/usr/local/opt/apr-util/bin:$PATH"
PERL_MM_OPT="INSTALL_BASE=$HOME/perl5" cpan local::lib Git::SVN SVN::Core
```

Verify installed modules by:

```
PERL5LIB="$HOME/perl5" cpan -l | grep SVN
```

Then configure Perl as following (based on `brew info perl` steps):

```
eval "$(perl -I$HOME/perl5/lib/perl5 -Mlocal::lib=$HOME/perl5)"
```

Finally run Git's SVN:

```
PERLLIB="$HOME/perl5" git svn clone https://svn.somecode.example.com/svn/trunk
```

---

If you're still stuck, try GitHub and [GitLab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/import/svn.html) websites which offer migration with a Git/SVN.

E.g. in GitHub, create a new repository, then import the project by pasting old repository’s clone URL.

Answer (score 0):

The error message says:

```
$ git svn --version
Can't locate SVN/Core.pm in @INC (you may need to install the SVN::Core module) (@INC contains: /usr/local/opt/subversion/lib/perl5 /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.31.1/share/perl5 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Perl/5.28/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Perl/5.28/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Library/Perl/5.30/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Library/Perl/5.30 /Network/Library/Perl/5.30/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Network/Library/Perl/5.30 /Library/Perl/Updates/5.30.2 /System/Library/Perl/5.30/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/5.30 /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.30/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.30) at /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.31.1/share/perl5/Git/SVN/Utils.pm line 6.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.31.1/share/perl5/Git/SVN/Utils.pm line 6.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.31.1/share/perl5/Git/SVN.pm line 25.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.31.1/share/perl5/Git/SVN.pm line 32.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.31.1/libexec/git-core/git-svn line 23.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.31.1/libexec/git-core/git-svn line 23.
```

This is because git-svn is implemented by Perl, it needs a Perl library called `SVN::Core` to run。
Changing the first line of `git-svn` script from `#!/usr/bin/perl` to `#!/usr/local/bin/perl` **won't fix this error!!!** Because this just changes the Perl library from `system default version` to `brew installed version`。If the `brew installed version` doesn't contains `SVN::Core`, it'll still fail:

```
$ git svn --version
Can't locate SVN/Core.pm in @INC (you may need to install the SVN::Core module) (@INC contains: /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.31.1/share/perl5 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Perl/5.28/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Perl/5.28/darwin-thread-multi-2level /usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.34.0/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.34.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level /usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.34.0/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.34.0 /usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.34.0/lib/perl5/5.34.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level /usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.34.0/lib/perl5/5.34.0 /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.34.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.34.0) at /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.31.1/share/perl5/Git/SVN/Utils.pm line 6.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.31.1/share/perl5/Git/SVN/Utils.pm line 6.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.31.1/share/perl5/Git/SVN.pm line 25.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.31.1/share/perl5/Git/SVN.pm line 32.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.31.1/libexec/git-core/git-svn line 23.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.31.1/libexec/git-core/git-svn line 23.
```

Note that the Perl version has been changed, but the error still exists. Because there is no `SVN:Core` in the directories indicated by `@INC`.

Now some answers may tell you to install `SVN::Core` by `cpan SVN::Core`, **Don't do that!!!** This won't solve the problem! Because the version of `SVN::Core` it installed, may not match with your SVN version:

```
$ git svn --version
error: git-svn died of signal 11
```

By the way, cpan is rubbish, don't use it to install anything. It compiles the source before installation but cannot control the compile flags/options, and it cannot uninstall things that are installed by itself.

---

**Here is the right solution:**

The corresponding Perl libraries are already installed when you installed `svn`, and `brew` has already told you:

```
$ brew info svn
subversion: stable 1.14.1 (bottled), HEAD
Version control system designed to be a better CVS
https://subversion.apache.org/
/usr/local/Cellar/subversion/1.14.1_2 (234 files, 32.1MB) *
  Poured from bottle on 2021-06-02 at 15:52:30
From: https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/homebrew-core.git/Formula/subversion.rb
License: Apache-2.0
==> Dependencies
Build: openjdk ✘, pkg-config ✘, python@3.9 ✔, scons ✘, swig ✘
Required: apr ✔, apr-util ✔, gettext ✔, lz4 ✔, openssl@1.1 ✔, utf8proc ✔
==> Options
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version
==> Caveats
svntools have been installed to:
  /usr/local/opt/subversion/libexec

The perl bindings are located in various subdirectories of:
  /usr/local/opt/subversion/lib/perl5

You may need to link the Java bindings into the Java Extensions folder:
  sudo mkdir -p /Library/Java/Extensions
  sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/libsvnjavahl-1.dylib /Library/Java/Extensions/libsvnjavahl-1.dylib
==> Analytics
install: 33,749 (30 days), 67,978 (90 days), 239,148 (365 days)
install-on-request: 33,129 (30 days), 67,011 (90 days), 229,097 (365 days)
build-error: 0 (30 days)
```

We can see that the Perl bindings are located in `/usr/local/opt/subversion/lib/perl5`, we just need to let `git-svn` use this path. With a little investigation of `git-svn` script, we can see this behavior is controlled by an environment variable called `GITPERLLIB`:

```perl
$ head /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.31.1/libexec/git-core/git-svn
#!/usr/bin/perl

use lib (split(/:/, $ENV{GITPERLLIB} || '/usr/local/Cellar/git/2.31.1/share/perl5:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Perl/5.28/darwin-thread-multi-2level:/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Perl/5.28/darwin-thread-multi-2level'));
# Copyright (C) 2006, Eric Wong <normalperson@yhbt.net>
# License: GPL v2 or later
```

So the right way to solve this problem is to add the following code to your `bashrc` or `zshrc`:

```bash
export GITPERLLIB=/usr/local/opt/subversion/lib/perl5/site_perl/$<your_perl_version>/darwin-thread-multi-2level
```

Problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue too on OSX Ventura, and none of the other answers got me all the way there. First I made sure I installed `subversion`, `git` and `git-svn` via homebrew. Then I used the excellent answer from @guo-ang to export the `GITPERLLIB` path.

However, when I followed @guo-ang's answer, my error changed from complaining about a missing SNV/Core.pm to:

```
Can't locate Git/SVN.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Git::SVN module)
```

So instead of just adding the path to the subversion perl libraries, I also needed to add the path to the git perl libraries as well. So my final export included both paths separated by a `:`

```bash
export GITPERLLIB=/usr/local/opt/subversion/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.30.3/darwin-thread-multi-2level:/usr/local/opt/git/share/perl5
```

Note that the above version number in the path is specific to my installed version of subversion and will likely be different on your system.

After including both paths in the `GITPERLLIB` environment variable my `git svn` command ran successfully.